# How to add implicit method to string

Tags: scala, akka

How to write implicit method to string to log directly.

Below Code works Fine :

```
case class Worker(name: String) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
      override def receive: Receive = {
        case string: String => log.info("string received")
        case _              => log.info("unknown message received")
      }
    }
```

Want to add .log implicit method to string and it should call log.info("message") like below :

```
case class Worker(name: String) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case string: String => "string received".log
    case _              => "unknown message received".log
  }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the images and paste the code

Comment: removed images and added the code.

Comment: Isn't that the second approach less readable/a bit confusing? For me, it's like referring to a .log file.

Comment: In both the cases log will print into the console only. Implicit "your message".log should internally call the log.info("your message")

Comment: Take a look to [**Implicit Classes**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like that?

```
trait LoggableString {this: ActorLogging =>

  private val logger = log //since there's name collision, we need to capture log method

  implicit class RichString(s: String) {
    def log() = logger.info(s)
  }

}

class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with LoggableString {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg => "Hello".log
  }
}
```

Or another solution suggested by Alexey Romanov:

```
trait ExtendedActorLogging extends ActorLogging {this: Actor =>

  private val logger =  log

  implicit class RichString(s: String) {
    def log() = logger.info(s)
  }

}

class MyActor extends Actor with ExtendedActorLogging {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg => "Hello".log
  }
}
```

Comment: Or `trait LoggableString extends ActorLogging`, so you don't need to duplicate them in every actor. You can use `this[LoggableString].log` to avoid the need for `val logger`.

Comment: Thanks @Krzysztof Atłasik.